# There was a failure executing the receive pipeline . Source : "ESB Dispatcher"

Tags: biztalk, esb, esb-toolkit-2.1

I am using BizTalk ESB Toolkit 2.3. My objective is to route a message based on the message context.

I am using an one-way receive port to receive the message with a receive location using "FILE" Adapter.
In the receive location I am using the "ItinerarySelectReceivePipeline" and I am setting the following properties for the pipeline :

Stage 1 - XML Disassembler

AllowUnrecogonizedMessage : False
RecoverableInterchangeMessage : False 
ValidateDocument : False

Stage 2 - ESB Itinerary Selector

IgnoreErrorKey : False
ItineraryFactKey : Resolver.Itinerary
ResolverConnectionString : ITINERARY:\name=ESBDemo;version=1.0

Stage 3 - ESB Dispatcher

Enabled - True

Endpoint - ""

MapName - ""

RoutingServiceName - Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Routing

TransformServiceName - Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Services.Transform

- Using a dynamic send port I am routing the messages based on the message context.
- From the "ESBDemo" itinerary I call a BRE to execute a Policy.

But when I am sending a message(in File format) to an On-Ramp service , I am getting the following error in the event Log:

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines.ItinerarySelectReceiveXml, Microsoft.Practices.ESB.Itinerary.Pipelines, Version=2.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "ESB Dispatcher" Receive Port: "ReceivePortFILEAdapter" URI: "C:\Users\muralsr\Documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ESBPluralSightDemo\In*.xml" Reason: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.

**Note** : I am using a BRE Resolver in my Itinerary during which I got the above error. But, when I am using Static resolver, I was able to route the message to my destination.

How to resolve the above?

Answer (score 0):

From the error it seems like you are trying to log something to Event Log and its failing there. Also, the message seems to be failing in the ESB Dispatcher component. Are you using any transforms in the itinerary that are logging to Event Logs. 
Try removing the logging code and retry.
Also, your BRE Resolver the Resolver connection String should be like :

```
BRI:\\policy=<PolicyName>;version=;useMsg=True;
```